# 700D how to blink on over-exposure?

Tags: canon, exposure, highlights

How can I blink pixels that are over-exposured, on my brand new Canon 700D? I just can't find the setting for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the top of page 272 in the [manual for the 700D](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300010890/03/EOS_700D_Instruction_Manual_v2_EN.pdf) it says:

> When the shooting information is displayed, any overexposed areas of
>   the image will blink. To obtain more image detail in the overexposed
>   areas, set the exposure compensation to a negative amount and shoot
>   again.

Meaning switch to the shooting information display, by pressing **INFO** and you'll get the highlight alert.

Comment: no!!! Info button will not show the highlights. This should be explicite enabled from menu as I explain in my answer

Comment: It is on page 272. But that does not help me because I cannot make it blink :-( even when shooting information is displayed. I just took a totally over-exposed image, pressed [preview] button and then [Info] button two times. Histogram and shooing information IS displayed, but pixels are NOT BLINKING.

Comment: @nagylzs, you should enable it from the menu

Comment: Yes, but where? I cannot find it in the menu. The term "highlight alert" appears only on page 272 of the manual. It does not say where to turn it off/on.

Comment: @nagylzs I think Romeo is using a Canon 70D or alike. That camera has that option. If I'm not mistaken the menu of the 700D lacks that entry. For all I know the alert should be shown when shooting information is displayed.

Comment: @Hugo, you are right, i use 70D and there this is a option. As I read from the manual you are correct, for 700d this should be visible via pressing info button in preview mode :)

Answer (score 3):

On the Canon 700D/Rebel T5i, it is not possible to see the "Highlight Alert Blinks" in a full screen preview mode.

The User has to set the display to one of the histogram Modes where the histogram is displayed on the right and a small thumbnail preview with the flashing Highlights Alert is displayed on the left.

If you click through quickly, you can miss it.

On the 70D, you enable the Highlight Alert in the 2nd playback menu and get a full screen display when previewing.